# ¿Cuándo se deben usar los símbolos "=" y ":" al añadir propiedades a un componente?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

Siguiendo el [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html) de `angular2` de `google` encuentro este fragmento de código:

```
export class AppComponent { 
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;
  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Yo transcribí este código en mi editor y me salía un error. Era simplemente que tenía `selectedHero = Hero;` en vez de `selectedHero: Hero;`, pero para mi lo más natural es que todas sean con `=` así como **title** y **heroes**.

¿Cuándo se debe usar el símbolo `=` y cuando `:` al añadir propiedades a un componente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La sintaxis completa en typescript es:

```
nombreDeIdentificador: tipoDeDato = valorInicial;
```

Por lo tanto, son piezas diferentes de la misma sintaxis.

Lo que va después de los dos puntos `:` es el tipo de datos, lo que va después del símbolo de igual `=` es el valor inicial de la variable.

En este ejemplo, los tipos de datos son inferidos por typescript.

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
heroes = HEROES;
```

Comment: Oh ya entiendo, pensé que era una cosa de angular.